# Cannot read property of 'Undefined' in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, phoenix-framework, v-for

This is my vue instance:

```
var vue = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-wrapper',
  data: {
    items: [],
}})
```

This is a v-for loop in my index.html.eex

```
<div v-for="item in items[0].subItems">{{item.name}}</div>
```

This is the script where I populate items, on document ready, with data passed during rendering from my Phoenix server.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      //Assign server-side parameters
      vue.items = <%= raw(@items) %>;
      console.log(vue.items);
    });
</script>
```

The log function shows the proper list of items that i want.
Problem is that I can't access them in the v-for loop, I'm getting:

```
vue.min.js:6 TypeError: Cannot read property 'subItems' of undefined
```

I can't access the first element, like items are still not populated.
How can I achieve this? I'm forced to initialize it in the index.html.eex file because I need the eex syntax to retrieve data passed from the server.

Comment: It's likely your Vue is created *before* the data is available, which results in the undefined.

Comment: Why are you loading your data via jQuery, instead of inside Vue (such as inside a  `mounted()` hook)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var vue = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-wrapper',
  data: {
    items: [{ subitems: []}],
})
```

Subitems was not defined in your example. This should fix it.

Comment: No. this is just an example of the scenario. Problem is that i can't access items[0] because it's undefined

Comment: Thats because you defined an empty array as items und and empty array is undefined on position 0.

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap your v-for into v-if="flag"
define your flag in instance as false
once your data comes from backend change the flag...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div v-if="items.length > 0" v-for="item in items[0].subItems">{{item.name}}</div>
```